# Replace non-unique values between data frames based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have `n_df`:

```
        x        y1    y2        y3        y4
0   -20.0 -0.839071  10.0  0.816164 -8795.000
1   -19.9 -0.865213   9.9  0.994372 -8667.619
2   -19.8 -0.889191   9.8  1.162644 -8541.472
3   -19.7 -0.910947   9.7  1.319299 -8416.553
4   -19.6 -0.930426   9.6  1.462772 -8292.856
..    ...       ...   ...       ...       ...
395  19.5 -0.947580   9.5  1.591630  6659.375
396  19.6 -0.930426   9.6  1.462772  6766.216
397  19.7 -0.910947   9.7  1.319299  6874.193
398  19.8 -0.889191   9.8  1.162644  6983.312
399  19.9 -0.865213   9.9  0.994372  7093.579
```

and `t_df`:

```
      x           y4
0  -15.0 -3820.085000
1   -6.0  -283.272160
2   -6.0  -282.533200
3   -3.4   848.923030
4   -3.4   -57.407845
5   -1.9    -9.010686
6   -1.5    -3.247304
7   -0.1     4.834770
8    5.3     0.933883
9    5.3     1.650013
10   5.3    97.658330
11  10.2   857.745500
12  14.4  2576.435000
```

I need to replace `y4` values from `n_df` with `y4` values from `t_df`, wherever they share the same `x` value.

There is one condition:

If there are multiple rows with same `x` in `t_df`, the `y4` value chosen is the one closer to the `y4` value of `n_df`.

**Example:**

`x` = 5.3 is in row `253` of `n_df`. That row has `y4` = `97.697`

In `t_df`, when `x` = `5.3`, the value closest is in row `10`, so `y4` from `n_df` becomes `97.658330`.

The output should be `n_df` with all replaced values

**EDIT:**

I was actually able to do most of the things, I got this output for `t_df`:

```
 x           y4
0  -15.0 -3820.085000
1   -6.0  -283.272160
4   -3.4   -57.407845
5   -1.9    -9.010686
6   -1.5    -3.247304
7   -0.1     4.834770
10   5.3    97.658330
11  10.2   857.745500
12  14.4  2576.435000
```

Now all that is left is to replace all `y4` values of `n_df` by these `y4` values of `t_df` when `x` is the same.

The output needs to be `n_df` with these 13 values changed

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this `n_df` as example:

```
        x  y1      y4
252 -20.0   0  23.345
253   5.3   1  97.697
254   5.3   2  12.345
```

You can use a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html), however it is a bit capricious so you need some pre- and post-processing (`by` key cannot be a float, `on` key must be sorted and temporarily renamed, the index must be preserved):

```
s = (pd.merge_asof(n_df.astype({'x': str}).reset_index()
                   .sort_values(by='y4').rename(columns={'y4': 'y4_'}),
                   t_df.astype({'x': str}).sort_values(by='y4'),
                   by='x', left_on='y4_', right_on='y4')
       .set_index('index')['y4']
     )

n_df['y4'] = s

print(n_df)
```

Output:

```
        x  y1         y4
252 -20.0   0        NaN
253   5.3   1  97.658330
254   5.3   2   1.650013
```

If you want to keep the original values in case of no match:

```
n_df['y4'] = s.fillna(n_df['y4'])
```

Output:

```
        x  y1         y4
252 -20.0   0  23.345000
253   5.3   1  97.658330
254   5.3   2   1.650013
```

Comment: thanks for your help. It seemed to work at first but something strange is happening. I've been testing the output for more than an hour. For some values it works perfectly, but others are not replaced, and I can't find a pattern of the numbers that are not being replaced, so I don't understand why.

Comment: I don't know if it is because of this but I should mention that In this example I only used y4 but I repeated your code for y1, y2 and y3 as well because I have values from those 4 columns to replace

Comment: @PeterM I suspect this has to do with floating point precision, I suggest you use `.round(2).astype({'x': str})` in place of `.astype({'x': str})` to force a given precision

Comment: Tried what you said but that doesn't seem to be the problem. I will give you an example: on column `y3`, there 4 of the y-values that needed to be replaced, corresponding to `x`= -12.5, `x` = -12.4, `x`= -12.1, `x`= -11.2 , only 2 of them got replaced.

Comment: Best if you provide a DataFrame constructor as edit to your question

Comment: I think that won't be necessary, with your help I may have reached the output I wanted. Tomorrow I will take an hour or so to confirm if the values are correct. Thank you